# Apache Randomly returns false on setlocale

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, setlocale

```
$s = null;
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')
        var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es'));
    else            
        if (!($s = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES'))) {

            if (!($s = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.iso88591'))) {
                if (!($s = setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_DO.utf8'))) {
                    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'spanish');
                }
            }
        }
    var_dump($s);
```

While trying to show a date using strftime, I encountered that sometimes I got it in English and sometimes in Spanish. Looking for the reason, I found out setlocale call sometimes returns false instead of the locale (which is available) I was trying to set, es_ES. I wrote a test code to try to set other Spanish locales if the previews attempts failed. Any clue on why is this happening?

[Locale shown on some refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsYbj.png)
[Locale shown in some others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYCo6.png)

Comment: Started for me after switching to php7